# Why are there discrepancies between client message signatures?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, signature, ethereumjs

I have been investigating message signing using an Ethereum account, and have become somewhat bemused by the different signatures that I receive from different clients and different libraries.

I have attempted to get answers by contacting library/client creators directly but have gotten no definitive answers.

When I utilise jsonrpc to send off a signing (`web3.eth.sign`) request to a Parity (1.6.6) backend, and a Geth (1.6.1) backend I get the following signatures back:

**Geth**
0xf6e5ce6040407c688c54c4b15949923e94651790afe4c53070c4765869cdbd713e4ea40b3b6f4a59397cb6a0880f265e9d1a0d1ed97fa9b757dc3799086fe6b91c

**Parity**
0x1cf6e5ce6040407c688c54c4b15949923e94651790afe4c53070c4765869cdbd713e4ea40b3b6f4a59397cb6a0880f265e9d1a0d1ed97fa9b757dc3799086fe6b9

Now.. I do not have an in depth understanding of elliptical curve cryptography, but i can see here that Geth returns a RSV format signature, and Parity a VRS.

**Question 1**
Is there a consistent way of determining which format the signature is in (for backwards compatibility)?

Now.. I am trying to work with these signatures using the fantastic [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util) library.

Utilising their `ecsign` method returns me a completely different signature:

0x1557765e35991c5ef5b09f7a7b4061be1e8daef873c94dc79089a861ec3284564b8fa3938f4a9f729c465c6bb9e23b80e6e91ae83a4e44fb39e70a11b467992500

I managed to recreate this signature from my Geth/Parity signatures by calling their `toRpcSig` method with the r,s, and v values extracted from the Geth/Parity sigs.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/13c9a030323691fd3d024c2793e7307b24378b6a/index.js#L375) it seems to concatenate `Buffer` versions of these values and converts the result to a string.

**Question 2**
Why does ethereumjs-util do this?

The end result is that geth, Parity, and ethereumjs-util all return different signatures when signing an arbitrary message. Etherscan, and etherchain have signature verification libraries which believe the ethereumjs-util signature to be correct. This may well be because they use the library under the hood. If this is correct..

**Question 3**
Why do Geth and Parity both return incorrect message signatures?

There seems to be a lot of github discussions etc about appending prefixes to messages before signing them etc, yet seemingly no-one has addressed the issue of client inconsistencies in signing.. which in my opinion is pretty important.

Comment: Are you aware of this discussion? Might wish to subscribe. https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/5490

Comment: Thanks for the link. i had seen that diagram elsewhere. So essentially as of yet there is no client consensus on what a valid signature is?

Comment: Gavin just posted a statement in the issue linked above. He says parity follows the Ethereum wiki specification.

Comment: To make matters worse, TREZOR went in a different direction and decided to not use message.length as a returned ASCII integer, but convert it into a varInt. It's a shit-show.